# Find maximum length of silence throughout an audio file

Tags: linux, sox

I need to find the maximum length of silence in any audio file, but throughout its duration, i.e., not only at the beginning or end. I've got a method to trim complete silence from file, by which I can get the length of silence using subtraction on the resulting lengths.
However, I need to eliminate only continuous silence, so that I can compare them to the maximum silence duration.

Here is what I have so far:

```
val1=`sox --i -D 123left.wav`
val2=`sox --i -D 123lefttrim.wav`
sum=0
total=`echo "$val1-$val2" | bc`
echo $total
```

Comment: consider editing your question to separately include the output from the 2 `sox -i ...` commands. Is the output just a number? What you have outlined should work, excepting the var `sum` seems to never be used. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for reply

123lefttrim.wav is silence removed file using command:
    `sox 123left.wav 123lefttrim.wav silence 1 0.1 1% -1 0.1 1%`
So all i am doing is finding diff in length of trimmed and original audio file, which gives me total duration of silence in original file.

But i need a method to find maximum continuous silence in the original audio file.

Comment: I've had a tiny bit of experience with sox, but I guess I'd really be surprised if you'll be able to extract the one and only 'max value of continuous silence from an audio file' with just sox. If you really need that, you'lll probably have to extend the sox processing and add an argument just to handle that. ALSO, I just notice, add more tags to your question, some `sox` experts probably aren't watching for linux tagged questions. Would also recommand adding `bash` or `bat` depending on your enviro. FINALLY, look on web for sox specific users and devloper email grps to ask your Q. Good luck!